# Inserindo dados na List em C#

Tags: c#

Sou novo na área de programação e não sei como se faz para obter dados do teclado para inserir nas listas, queria perguntador por exemplo informações de um carro e guardar em uma lista.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CadastroVeiculos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            List<CadastroCarro> cadastroCarros = new List<CadastroCarro>();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Lista de Veículos");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (CadastroCarro carro in cadastroCarros)
            {

                if (carro.YearManufacturer == "2000")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                      "Modelo: " + carro.CarModel + " "
                    + "\nCor: " + carro.CarColor + " "
                    + "\nFabricante: " + carro.CarManufacturer + " "
                    + "\nPlaca: " + carro.CarPlate + " "
                    + "\nAno Fabricação: " + carro.YearManufacturer);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CadastroVeiculos
{
    class CadastroCarro
    {
        
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
        public string CarManufacturer { get; set; }
        public string CarPlate { get; set; }
        public string CarColor { get; set; }
        public int NumberPorts { get; set; }
        public string YearManufacturer { get; set; }

        public CadastroCarro()
        {

        }

        public CadastroCarro(string carModel, string carManufacturer, string carPlate, string carColor, int numberPorts)
        {
            this.CarModel = carModel;
            this.CarManufacturer = carManufacturer;
            this.CarPlate = carPlate;
            this.CarColor = carColor;
            this.NumberPorts = numberPorts;
        }


       
    }


}
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda [`Console.ReadLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

A sua classe `CadastroCarro` não precisa usar nos atributos a palavra `this`, mas isso é só um detalhe, caso queira, pode manter. Antes de adicionar elementos à sua lista, você precisa guardar os valores digitados pelo usuário nas respectivas variáveis.

Exemplo:

```
Console.Write("Modelo: "); // aqui você pergunta para o usuário.  
string carModel = Console.ReadLine(); // o método Console.ReadLine() é o responsável por guardar a informação que o usuário digitou dentro da variável 'carModel'
```

Após guardar todos os valores nas variáveis, aí sim você conseguirá adicionar esses valores em uma lista utilizando uma função específica do C# que adiciona elementos em listas.

Exemplo:

```
cadastroCarros.Add(carModel, carManufacturer, carPlate, carColor, numberPorts);
```